# python if and else statements calculating employees pay

Tags: python

I'm having a little trouble with this assignment its about calculating the employees pay it goes like  Write a Python program that prompts the user for an hourly rate and a number of hours worked and computes a pay amount. Any hours worked over 40 are paid at time and a half (1.5 times the normal hourly rate). Write a version of the program  using the if/else my code so far is this

```
hours = int(input('how many hours did you work? '))
rate = 1.50
rate = (hours/2)+hours*(rate+1.5)
if hours<40:
 print("you earn",rate)
```

Comment: At least try, or explain what your problem is.  As is your question is essentially "do my homework for me"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a homework problem with minimal attempts by the OP so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to input both the *hours* and *rate* from the user, you can do so like this:

```
hours = int(input('how many hours did you work? '))
rate = int(input('what is your hourly rate? '))
```

Then once you have those variables, you can start by calculating the overtime.

```
if hours > 40:
  # anything over 40 hours earns the overtime rate
  overtimeRate = 1.5 * rate
  overtime = (hours-40) * overtimeRate
  # the remaining 40 hours will earn the regular rate
  hours = 40
else:
  # if you didn't work over 40 hours, there is no overtime
  overtime = 0
```

Then calculate the regular hours:

```
regular = hours * rate
```

Your total pay is `regular + overtime`.

Comment: Should probably use float for hours and rate

Answer (score 2):

```
print("you earn", (hours + max(hours - 40, 0) * 0.5) * rate)
```

or for a golfed version

```
print("you earn", (hours*3-min(40,hours))*rate/2)
```

Comment: Looks very similar to a slightly wrong comment I made ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
pay = rate * min(hours, 40)
if hours > 40:
    pay += rate * 1.5 * (hours - 40)
```

To adjust the pay calculations depending on the number of hours worked.

You should probably become familiar with [this resource](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Comment: I want you writing my paychecks in the future! If I work 1 hour you pay me 40.

Comment: Haha, confusing `min` and `max` totally counts as an off-by-one error right?!

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- You need to prompt the user for their hourly rate as well.
- It's `rate * 1.5`, not `rate + 1.5`. That rate is only applied to hours *past* 40, so for the first 40 hours, you apply the regular rate:

  ```
  if hours <= 40:
      total = hours * rate
  else:
      total = 40 * rate + (hours - 40) * (1.5 * rate)
  ```

Comment: Don't even need the `if`.... just use: `hours * rate + max(hours - 40, 0) * (1.5 * rate)`

Comment: @JonClements. shouldn't that be `(0.5 * rate)`?

Comment: @gnibbler only if you're halving the rate for overtime?

Comment: @JonClements, you already get the `1` from `hours * rate`

Comment: @gnibbler errr.... *cough* - I was just checking to see if the student tests their code properly!? :)